# QTableView How to select multiple columns programmatically

Tags: c++, qt, multiple-columns, qtableview, qtgui

I'm trying to select two columns of QTableView in code. Unfortunatelly, when I call

```
tableView->selectColumn(1)
tableView->selectColumn(2)
```

it selects 1st column, deselects 1st column and selects 2nd column. Is it possible to select multiple columns in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just need to ensure to allow the user to select multiple columns, you need [to set up](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#selectionMode-prop) the [proper selection mode](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#SelectionMode-enum) as follows:

```
tableView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
```

If you would like to do this programatically, this is the way of doing it:

```
QModelIndexList itemSelection = tableView->selectionModel()->selectedColumns();
int currentColumn = itemSelection.first().column();
QItemSelection selectedItems = tableView->selectionModel()->selection();

tableView->selectColumn(1);
selectedItems.merge(tableView->selectionModel()->selection(), QItemSelectionModel::Select);
tableView->selectColumn(2);
selectedItems.merge(tableView->selectionModel()->selection(), QItemSelectionModel::Select);

tableView->selectionModel()->clearSelection();
tableView->selectionModel()->select(selectedItems, QItemSelectionModel::Select);
```

Disclaimer: the code has been taken [from here](http://www.qt-coding.com/2013/11/28/tip-of-the-day-select-multiple-rows-in-qtableview-programatically/), and then modified to suit your need.

Answer (score 1):

`selectionModel.select()` in its *select columns* mode may be preferable.

In PyQt:

```
columns = [1,2,3]
indexes = [model.index(0, c) for c in columns]
mode = QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.Select | QtCore.QItemSelectionModel.Columns
[tableView.selectionModel().select(index, mode) for i in indexes]
```